# Connection handlers

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I would like to setup a handler for when my ESP8266 is connected, so that it returns the IP address (among other things). I am calling a Network class method from my main class's setup function, and am not sure how to provide the necessary parameters to the handler. I attempted the following, but I get an error about how **ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function**.

I would love any feedback,

Thanks!

```
/* Network.h */
class Network{
    public:
        void connect(const char* ssid, const char* password);
        WiFiEventHandler deviceDidConnect;
        void onDeviceConnected(const WiFiEventStationModeGotIP& evt);
}

/* Network.cpp */
void Network::connect(const char* ssid, const char* password) {

    WiFi.persistent(false);

    if (WiFi.status() == WL_DISCONNECTED) {
        deviceDidConnect = WiFi.onStationModeGotIP(&onDeviceConnected);
        // Not sure how to handle it here...
    }

}

void onDeviceConnected(const WiFiEventStationModeGotIP& evt) {
  Serial.print("Station connected, IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

/* MyApp */
#include "Network.h"

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    network.connect(SSID, PASSWORD);
}
```

**Updated on 11/08/18:**

My goal is to create an Arduino library to handle my connections.
I noticed that if I leave the *connect* method and the *WifiEventHandler* in the header file, but move the *onDeviceConnected* method signature (void onDeviceConnected(const WiFiEventStationModeGotIP& evt);) to **Network.cpp** (after I include **Network.h**), then the sketch compiles and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I was under the misguided notion that all methods in a custom Arduino library should be exposed either as Public or Private in the header file, whereas only methods that need to be shared need be exposed. It makes sense.